# No route found for "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/library_list"

Tags: symfony

Soy nueva en symfony e hice esta pequeña ruta para poder visualizarla, pero tengo el error de que el navegador no encuentra esa ruta.

codigo:

```
<?php

//  Todas las clases deben de llevar un namespace
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route; //Empleo la anotacion que instale
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;



// Declaro la libreria (estso me da metodos utiles para el controlador)
class LibraryController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/library/list",name = "library_list") 
     * 
     */

    // Creo la primera accion
    // La accion es un metodo de mi clase controller que esta asociado a las rutas

    public function list(){

        // devuelvo un objeto de la clase response
        $response = new Response(); 

        $response->setContent('<div>Hola Mundo de Mili</div>');

        return $response;
        
    }
}
```

Previamente instale las anotaciones pero no se me creo el archivo annotations.yaml, es por falta de eso?

[image: Imagen del error al ingresar a mi ruta]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentas acceder usando el nombre de la ruta *library_list*, y debes acceder con el primer parametro definido en el @Route.

> @Route("/library/list",name = "library_list")

Es decir **127.0.0.1:8000/library/list**